# Find the energy for which the motion under the central force is circular

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

I am told that a particle moves under the action of an attractive central force $F=\frac{-k}{r^2}\hat r,$ with angular momentum $L.$

I am asked to find the energy for which the motion is circular and the radius of the circle.
So far I have said the following:

$$L=\vec r \times m\vec v = 
\begin{vmatrix} \hat r & \hat\theta & \hat z \\ 
r & 0 & 0 
\\ m \dot r & m r \dot \theta & 0
\end{vmatrix}
= mr^2\dot\theta\hat z .$$

Using $F=ma,$ we have that $$\frac{-k}{r^2}=m(\ddot r-r \dot \theta^2)$$

Then using angular momentum substitute in for $\dot\theta$ giving $$\frac{-k}{r^2}=m(\ddot r-\frac{L^2}{m^2r^3})$$

Rearranging this then gives $$m\ddot r-\frac{L^2}{mr^3}+\frac{k}{r^2}=0$$

Then multiply by $\dot r$ to give $$m\ddot r \dot r-\frac{L^2\dot r}{mr^3}+\frac{k\dot r}{r^2}=0$$

Then we have $$\frac{1}{2}m\dot r^2+\frac{L^2}{2mr^2}-\frac{k}{r}=\text{ constant }=E$$

To find the radius I then set $\frac{dP}{dr}=0$ where P is the effective potential $(\frac{L^2}{2mr^2}-\frac{k}{r}).$

This gives me $$\frac{L^2}{mr^3}=\frac{k}{r^2}$$

And so the radius is $$r=\frac{L^2}{mk}$$

How do I find for what energy the motion is circular though?

Comment: The earth orbits around the sun under an approximately attractive central force.  Its orbit is not close to being a circle.  This orbit is almost an ellipse.  Some comets that enter the solar system also experience the same central force, but their orbits follow hyperbolic paths.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478440/defining-the-initial-conditions-for-a-planetary-motion-to-have-a-circular-orbit). It will help. :)

Comment: @H.R. I've had a read through it but none of it means a great deal to me. Could you try to explain how to do this using a similar style approach to what I have used above?

Comment: @Si.0788: Did you read my answer there? Energy is conservative in this problem. so what do you need to specify the initial energy? The initial velocity, right?

Comment: @H.R. Yes. That makes sense. How would you find the initial velocity though?

Comment: @Si.0788: The procedure of finding initial velocity is explained in my answer in the post I mentioned.

Comment: @H.R. I still don't see how that applies here. There you said that $v_0=\sqrt{\frac{GM}{r_0}}$, but I don't have that information here.

Comment: @Si.0788: OK, let me explain from scratch. The path that the particle will have depends on the **initial conditions**. You should set the initial conditions in a way that the path becomes **circular**. Then I proved there that if the path is a **circle** then the initial conditions should be $\left\{ \matrix{
  {{\bf{r}}_0}.{{\bf{v}}_0} = 0,\,\,\,\,{{\bf{r}}_0} \ne 0,\;\;\;{{\bf{v}}_0} \ne 0 \hfill \cr 
  {v_0} = \left\| {{{\bf{v}}_0}} \right\| = \sqrt {{{GM} \over {{r_0}}}}  \hfill \cr}  \right.$.